# GADBannerView does not set height

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

Does anybody know how to show 50pt-height GADBannerView programmatically?

In my viewDidLoad,

```
int heightOfBanner = 50;
GADBannerView *banner = 
 [[GADBannerView alloc]
 initWithAdSize:GADAdSizeFullWidthPortraitWithHeight(heightOfBanner)
 origin:CGPointMake(0, CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner).height)];
banner.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
banner.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:banner];

[banner loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

Above code does't show anything.

**But when heightOfBanner set to be higher value(for example, 200), it works well(but banner's height is not 50).**

My podfile is below:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.0'
```

and I did "pod install" successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use exact dimensions to draw your `GADBannerView`. You should set its frame and origin relative to the screen dimensions. This will display your `GADBannerView` on the bottom of the screen

```
    // Get device screen size
    // For example, screenBounds on an iPhone 6 will look like this
    // screenBounds.origin.x == 0
    // screenBounds.origin.y == 0
    // screenBounds.size.width == 375
    // screenBounds.size.height == 667
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    // Setup AdMob view
    // Create the GADBannerView
    adMobView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];

    // Use your BANNER_UNIT_ID
    adMobView.adUnitID = BANNER_UNIT_ID;
    adMobView.rootViewController = self;
    [adMobView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

    // This sets the frame origin at (0,0) which would be the top left of the device screen
    // screenBounds.size.width and adMobView.bounds.size.height sets the size of the GADBannerView
    [adMobView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenBounds.size.width, adMobView.bounds.size.height)];

    // This will take the center of our GADBannerView and move it to a point (x,y)
    // We want our GADBannerView.center in the center of the device screen
    // So lets get the width of our screen and divide it by 2. We do this with screenBounds.size.width / 2
    // We also want our GADBannerView to be at the bottom of the screen
    // So lets get the height of our screen with screenBounds.size.height
    // Remember were talking about the center of our GADBannerView here so if we just set it to that
    // Half of our GADBannerView's height will be cut off by the bottom of the screen
    // So lets subtract half of our GADBannerView's height to fix that with adMobView.bounds.size.height / 2
    adMobView.center = CGPointMake(screenBounds.size.width / 2, screenBounds.size.height - (adMobView.bounds.size.height / 2));

    // Add it to our view
    [self.view addSubview:adMobView];
```

Comment: @TsuyoshiEndo I've updated my answer so the width of the `GADBannerView` stretches across the width of entire screen.

Comment: It works well!!
I understood _Don't use exact dimensions_ and _use center_ when I want to locate specific point.
So, When I use one of UIViewControllers in UINavigationController, does this code work well?

Comment: I got it.
[I made it temporarily (so dirty..) but should work also in UINavigationController](https://github.com/etsuyoshi/UINavigationWithGADBannerView.git) using @DanielStorm code. Thank you for a good answer.